# Activity lifecycle is not working properly in my LG optimous device

Tags: android, android-activity, device, lifecycle

```
Activity lifecycle is not working properly in my LG optimous device.
```

Whenever I called another activity and from there when I pressed back button always onCreate method is calling. This problem is only happening in LG optimous device (android 4.0.4) but in other devices it is working fine.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action buttons
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_cal:
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Calculator.class));
        return true;
    case R.id.menu_formula:
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Formulas.class));
        return true;
    case R.id.menu_contact:
        startActivity(new Intent(this, ContactActivity.class));
        return true;
    case R.id.menu_videos:
        startActivity(new Intent(this, VideosActivity.class));
        return true;
    case R.id.menu_settings:
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplication(), Settings.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1001);
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check if `onStop()` method is being called while starting your new `activity`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your development settings, may be the option "Don't keep activities" is enabled, that means the activity will destroy itself when it's out of view. Just disabled the option and everything will work as normal. Hope I point out the right direction.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable solution. You are right, after change the settings it is working fine.